# How to select next greatest Date based on customer match in EXCEL?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn0ir.png)

I need a formula to pull in the next greatest date based on customer match from a another set of data.

So on one tab I have Customer JOE who has a service date of 1/1/19. On another tab is all service dates JOE had ranging from Dec 2018-Feb 2019.  I need to pull in the next service date after the 1/1/19 from the original tab

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates in Sheet2 are contiguous without any blanks, you can use this:

```
=INDEX(dates,MATCH(A1,dates,0)+1)
```

Just adjust the ranges as needed

[image]

(Note: I have `dates` as a named range, column D (and this goes all the way to `2/28/2019`)

Comment: How do I match on customer though? I gave the example of JOE but I have multiple customer names within the data

Comment: @Jillian please edit your OP with sample data and sample expected output.

Comment: screenshot of sample data added

Answer (score 1):

A non-contiguous solution. **[edit: CSE formula]**.

Next Date `=SMALL(IF(datesTab!allDatesRange>thisViewingDate,datesTab!allDatesRange),1)`

Or `MIN` without the second argument `,1`.

Test to see if there was a next date:

- `SMALL` returns an error (`#NUM!`) when nothing is found.
- `MIN` returns 0 (`Jan 0, 1900`) when nothing is found.

If there are two services on the same date and the dates are only dates (and not a complete timestamp), this will not return the second date. In this case of date only, it gets complicated keeping track of whether the date displayed is the first service for the date or the third and final...